# I am web mail for my application. no mail are receive in my account local mail are working fine but web mail are not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am using web mail in my application configuring some credentials in the appsetting.json file. My problem is that registration mails are not arriving.[image]

I dont know how to solve this.

Comment: Need code instead of an image, also required minimal example to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you use gmail, you can setup like this and sure that `Turn On Access for less secure apps` by https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en-GB

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

var fromAddress = new MailAddress("from@gmail.com", "From Name");
var toAddress = new MailAddress("to@example.com", "To Name");
const string fromPassword = "fromPassword";
const string subject = "Subject";
const string body = "Body";

var smtp = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
    Port = 587,
    EnableSsl = true,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
};
using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
{
    Subject = subject,
    Body = body
})
{
    smtp.Send(message);
}
```

More reference at [Sending email in .NET through Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

Comment: Its Working fine But Some Mail Id are working good and then some mail id are not working. how can i write common way and then any option are enable in mail server side. And then i am using the email Templates

Comment: you can create config file for option at serverside and you also can save email template in xml file with mark like this Dear, {{sender}}

Comment: What is the problem some mail as been working fine and then some mail are not working